# How can see local images (put in assets folder)?

Tags: enyo

I can't manage to see my assets pictures in this ChessBoard view, though the navigator console doesn't show me any error :

```
enyo.kind({
    name: "PositionView",
    published: {
        fen: "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1",
        cellsize: 32,
        color: "#CCC"
    },
    fit: true,
    components: [
        {
            name: "canvas",
            kind: "enyo.Canvas",
            attributes: {width: 10, height: 10}
        }
    ],
    create: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);
    },
    rendered:function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this.computeCellSize();
        this.drawGrid();
        this.drawPieces();
        this.$.canvas.update();
    },
    drawGrid: function() {
        for (var line=0; line < 8; line++){
            for (var col=0; col < 8; col++){
                var compName = "abcdefgh"[col] + (8-line);
                var bgcolor = ((line+col)%2 == 0) ? "#CF3" : "#630";
                this.$.canvas.createComponent({
                    kind: "enyo.canvas.Rectangle",
                    bounds:{t:(line*this.cellsize), l:(col*this.cellsize), w:this.cellsize, h:this.cellsize},
                    color:bgcolor,
                    name: compName
                });
            }
        }
    },
    drawPieces: function(){
        var x = 3*this.cellsize;
        var y = 4*this.cellsize;
        this.$.canvas.createComponent({
            kind: "enyo.canvas.Image",
            bounds:{t:y, l:x, w:this.cellsize, h:this.cellsize},
            src: "assets/wn.svg"
        });
    },
    computeCellSize: function(){
        var screenWidth = enyo.dom.getWindowWidth();
        var screenHeight = enyo.dom.getWindowHeight();
        var minSize = screenWidth < screenHeight ? screenWidth : screenHeight;
        this.cellsize = Math.floor(minSize * 1.0 / 8);
        this.$.canvas.setAttribute('width', 8*this.cellsize);
        this.$.canvas.setAttribute('height', 8*this.cellsize);
    }
});
```

As you should have noticed, I am making grid cells dynamically (this works well) with the method drawGrid(), but the method drawPieces() doesn't seems to work, as I can't see the picture.

Apologizing for not using JsFiddle, it is because I don't know how to adapt my project so that it can fit in it.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the image tag is not loading in time to be rendered.  You might want to try delaying the call to update the canvas for a short time period.  I modified the fiddle previously posted and included an SVG image.  It doesn't render the first time for me, but when re-run it will render because it's in the browser cache:

http://jsfiddle.net/RoySutton/cxx57780/1

I wrapped your code above in the following to get it going on jsFiddle:

```
enyo.ready(function() {
...
    new enyo.Application({view: "PositionView"});
});
```

My previous thought about the width/height of the SVG doesn't seem to be correct so I have removed it from this answer.

Comment: Thank you. I've checked the svg source code with Kate editor, and the author already set up width/height in it. How should I override enyo.canvas.Image class in order to apply bounds : what is the simpler way ? Otherwise I could try to inline all the svg sources into the source code (easier for JSFiddle) if I can : what do you think about it ?

Comment: I have reworked my answer based on some more testing.

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking about using preload.js in order to delay canvas drawing, but I did not find how to integrate it with my Enyo kind (because to kind lifecycle management). Otherwise, I've already followed preload.js official example "with success".